# Getting an exception ORA-00942: table or view does not exist - when inserting into an existing table

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, ora-00942

I am getting below exception, when trying to insert a batch of rows to an existing table

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

I can confirm that the table exists in db and I can insert data to that table using oracle 
sql developer. But when I try to insert rows using preparedstatement in java, its throwing table does not exist error.

Please find the stack trace of error below

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTIoer.processError(TTIoer.java:289) 
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.Oall7.receive(Oall7.java:573) 
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.doOall7(TTC7Protocol.java:1889)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.parseExecuteFetch(TTC7Protocol.java:1093)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeNonQuery(OracleStatement.java:2047)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteOther(OracleStatement.java:1940) 
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout>>(OracleStatement.java:2709)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:589)
    at quotecopy.DbConnection.insertIntoDestinationDb(DbConnection.java:591)
    at quotecopy.QuoteCopier.main(QuoteCopier.java:72)
```

Can anyone suggest the reasons for this error ?

**Update :** Issue solved

There was no problem with my database connection properties or with my table or view name. The solution to the problem was very strange. One of the columns that I was trying insert was of Clob type. As I had a lot of trouble handling clob data in oracle db before, gave a try by replacing the clob setter with a temporary string setter and the same code executed with out any problems and all the rows were correctly inserted!!!.

> ie. peparedstatement.setClob(columnIndex, clob)

was replaced with

> peparedstatement.setString(columnIndex, "String")

Why an error table or view does exist error was throws for error in inserting clob data. Could anyone of you please explain ?

Thanks a lot for your answers and comments.

Comment: Well, i suppose "table or view does not exist". Can you show us the table definition and also your statement?

Comment: @aquero: Perhaps printing (and showing here) the query that produces this error will help.

Comment: @aquero: Please show us the Java code you're using.

Comment: For [BC]Lob's in oracle I think you have to insert a new record with a `null` Lob first and update it with the Lob data directly afterwards. (It's been while so I'm not entirely sure>)

Comment: @rsp - that was true of very old versions of the database.  I suppose it may still be true with JDBC calls.

Comment: Oracle throws the (unhelpful) 'ORA-00942' error if you try to insert/update LOB data the wrong way. I've had a similar problem with blobs, and I couldn't use the `setString()` workaround. The correct way is to first write your data into a blob using the `OutputStream` from `Blob.setBinaryStream()`, and then use that `Blob` object in `setBlob()`. See this [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html) for details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was no problem with my database connection properties or with my table or view name. The solution to the problem was very strange. One of the columns that I was trying insert was of Clob type. As I had a lot of trouble handling clob data in oracle db before, gave a try by replacing the clob setter with a temporary string setter and the same code executed with out any problems and all the rows were correctly inserted!!!.

> ie. peparedstatement.setClob(columnIndex, clob)

was replaced with

> peparedstatement.setString(columnIndex, "String")

Comment: This is not a proper solution! If you try to transfer an account data between databases then you will lose clob, blob data available in these columns.

Answer (score 14):

Oracle will also report this error if the table exists, but you don't have any privileges on it. So if you are sure that the table is there, check the grants.

Comment: That was exactly my case on a multi-user application that needed access (also for SELECT) to other schema. A tip for developers: RE-check this issue for NEW tables you may add, because easily forgotten (that's me)

Answer (score 11):

There seems to be some issue with setCLOB() that causes an ORA-00942 under some circumstances when the target table does exist and is correctly privileged. I'm having this exact issue now, I can make the ORA-00942 go away by simply not binding the CLOB into the same table.

I've tried setClob() with a java.sql.Clob and setCLOB() with an oracle.jdbc.CLOB but with the same result.

As you say, if you bind as a string the problem goes away - but this then limits your data size to 4k.

From testing it seems to be triggered when a transaction is open on the session prior to binding the CLOB. I'll feed back when I've solved this...checking Oracle support.

Answer (score 4):

@unbeli is right. Not having appropriate grants on a table will result in this error. For what it's worth, I recently experienced this. I was experiencing the exact problem that you described, I could execute insert statements through sql developer but would fail when using hibernate. I finally realized that my code was doing more than the obvious insert. Inserting into other tables that did not have appropriate grants. Adjusting grant privileges solved this for me.

Note: Don't have reputation to comment, otherwise this may have been a comment.

Comment: This is an answer for me, since it's a general case (also for SELECT). That was exactly my case on a multi-user application that needed access (also for SELECT) to other schema. A tip for developers: RE-check this issue for NEW tables you may add, because easily forgotten (that's me)

Answer (score 4):

I found how to solve this problem without using JDBC's setString() method which limits the data to 4K.

What you need to do is to use preparedStatement.setClob(int parameterIndex, Reader reader). At least this is what that worked for me. Thought Oracle drivers converts data to character stream to insert, seems like not. Or something specific causing an error.

Using a characterStream seems to work for me. I am reading tables from one db and writing to another one using jdbc. And i was getting table not found error just like it is mentioned above.  So this is how i solved the problem:

```
case Types.CLOB:   //Using a switch statement for all columns, this is for CLOB columns
        Clob clobData = resultSet.getClob(columnIndex); // The source db
        if (clobData != null) {
            preparedStatement.setClob(columnIndex, clobData.getCharacterStream());
        } else {
            preparedStatement.setClob(columnIndex, clobData);
        }
        clobData = null;
        return;
```

All good now.

Answer (score 4):

We experienced this issue on a BLOB column.  Just in case anyone else lands on this question when encountering this error, here is how we resolved the issue:

We started out with this:

```
            preparedStatement.setBlob(parameterIndex, resultSet.getBlob(columnName)); break;
```

We resolved the issue by changing that line to this:

```
        java.sql.Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob(columnName);
        if (blob != null) {
            java.io.InputStream blobData =  blob.getBinaryStream();
            preparedStatement.setBinaryStream(parameterIndex, blobData);
        } else {
            preparedStatement.setBinaryStream(parameterIndex, null);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your script providing the **schema name**, or do you rely on the user logged into the database to select the **default schema**?

It might be that you do not name the schema and that you perform your batch with a system user instead of the schema user resulting in the wrong execution context for a script that would work fine if executed by the user that has the target schema set as default schema. Your best action would be to include the schema name in the insert statements:

```
INSERT INTO myschema.mytable (mycolums) VALUES ('myvalue')
```

**update:** Do you try to bind the table name as bound value in your prepared statement? That won't work.

Comment: I changed my insert query to include the schema, but still getting the same exception

Comment: @aquero, can you edit your question and include the statement and the Java code that prepares, binds the values and executes?

Comment: please find the comments added in my question above, It was in issue in inserting clob data. But the exception thrown was table does not exist error. Thanks a lot for your help..:)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
Clob clob1;
while (rs.next()) {
   rs.setString(1, rs.getString("FIELD_1"));

   clob1 = rs.getClob("CLOB1");
   if (clob1 != null) {
      sta.setClob(2, clob1.getCharacterStream());
   } else {
      sta.setClob(2, clob1);
   }
   clob1 = null;

   sta.setString(3, rs.getString("FIELD_3"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are doing `INSERT` for `VARCHAR` but doing an `INSERT` then an `UPDATE` for `CLOB`?

If so, you'll need to grant `UPDATE` permissions to the table in addition to `INSERT`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64352414/1089967

Answer (score -1):

Here I got the solution for the question. The problem is on glass fish if you are using it. When you create JNDI name  make sure pool name is correct and pool name is the name of connection pool name that you are created.

[image]