# Connection Manager Prepare Statement syntax

Tags: java, oracle

This statement works fine when I run it in SQL developer, however, when I try and run it through the connection manager like this, I keep getting "table or view not found".  I was wondering if this is because there might be a different syntax rule with connection manager or what?  Does anyone have any insight into what the problem might be?  Thanks.

```
ps = con.prepareStatement("select receipts.ordernumber, receipts.part, receipts.location, receipts.site, 
                           receipts.orderqty,  receipts.supplier, receipts.mfr, receipts.mfrpart, 
                           receipts.ponumber, orders.poline, orders.porelease, orders.price, 
                           orders.uom, orders.currency_r, orders.datecreated, orders.datelate, 
                           orders.approval_time, orders.userid, orders.buyer, orders.note_r, 
                           orders.qtyopen, orders.orderstate, supplier.accountnumber, 
                           delivery.method, 
                           CASE WHEN delivery.method = 'EDI' and delivery.process = 'ORDER' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS EDI, 
                           receipts.userid " +
"from receipts, orders, supplier, delivery " + 
"where receipts.customerix=43 and 
       orders.wip_order = 1 and supplier.suppliercode = orders.supplier and 
       supplier.customerix = orders.customerix and 
       delivery.supplierix = supplier.supplierix and 
       receipts.consigned = '1' and 
       orders.custordernumber(+) = receipts.ordernumber AND 
       orders.CUSTOMERIX(+) = receipts.CUSTOMERIX and 
       receipts.exported=0 and 
       receipts.export_active=1 
       order by receipts.ordernumber");


            statement = update.prepareStatement(" update receipts set export_active = 1 where receiptix in " +
                "(SELECT receipts.receiptix FROM pours.receipts, pours.orders, pours.supplier " +
                "WHERE receipts.customerix =7021 AND orders.wip_order = 1 AND supplier.suppliercode = orders.supplier " +
                "AND supplier.customerix = orders.customerix " +
                "AND receipts.consigned = '1' AND orders.custordernumber(+) = receipts.ordernumber " +
                "AND orders.CUSTOMERIX(+) = receipts.CUSTOMERIX AND receipts.exported = 0)");
```

Comment: Are you sure your Java connection is connecting to the same schema that you connect to in SQL Developer?

Comment: @GriffeyDog Yeah, I am.  I have a couple of other queries in this file and one of them seems to work while the other two are also having this problem.  I thought it might be like [this problem here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561650/getting-an-exception-ora-00942-table-or-view-does-not-exist-when-inserting-in) but I'm not inserting any data in it or anything, just running the query.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Also, try making simpler queries to see if you can access data in the tables;

Regards!
/Thomas

Answer (score 0):

`I Think you went wrong with the DBName, for the connection..`Check once you had given the correct Database for the connection

You only gets this error when your Database Doesnt have this Tables

```
DB_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:DBName";
DB_USER = "user";
DB_PASSWORD = "password";
```