# dbunit - SQL exception

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, oracle, dbunit

I want to extract my database to FlatXmlDataSet. I use this tutorial:
    http://www.dbunit.org/faq.html#extract

my code looks:

```
Class driverClass = Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection jdbcConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:oracle:thin: <my parametres>", "<user>", "<password>");
IDatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection(jdbcConnection);

// full database export
IDataSet fullDataSet = connection.createDataSet();
FlatXmlDataSet.write(fullDataSet, new FileOutputStream("full.xml"));
```

and I have error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.dbunit.dataset.DataSetException:java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTable(DatabaseDataSet.java:316)
at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseTableIterator.getTable(DatabaseTableIterator.java:89)
at org.dbunit.dataset.stream.DataSetProducerAdapter.produce(DataSetProducerAdapter.java:83)
at org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlWriter.write(FlatXmlWriter.java:124)
at org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlDataSet.write(FlatXmlDataSet.java:341)
at db.main(db.java:26)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:195)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:876)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1175)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1498)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:406)
at org.dbunit.database.AbstractResultSetTable.<init>(AbstractResultSetTable.java:110)
at org.dbunit.database.ForwardOnlyResultSetTable.<init>(ForwardOnlyResultSetTable.java:59)
at org.dbunit.database.CachedResultSetTableFactory.createTable(CachedResultSetTableFactory.java:60)
at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTable(DatabaseDataSet.java:312)
... 5 more
```

I use:
-eclipse
-dbunit 2.4.5
-slf4j 1.5.8
-maven 3.04

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if your connection parameters are correctly spelled, the necessary permissions are set and that the tables from your database really exist. You can then take a look at this similar post [java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561650/getting-an-exception-ora-00942-table-or-view-does-not-exist-when-inserting-in).

Comment: Connections parameters are correct. About the tables, I have some tables, but i don't point out from which table it can read. This can cause problem?

Comment: Try to use a partial database export and add tables one by one as explained [here](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#extract). You should first check the [necessary permissions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c24privs.htm) for the username employed in your code to connect to the database.