# Getting ORA-00942: table or view does not exist using Blob in Java

Tags: java, oracle, prepared-statement, blob

I'm having problems when trying to insert in my ORACLE ddbb using PreparedStatement. Its seems to be related to the Blob data type than I'm handling.
In this link [changing type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561650/getting-an-exception-ora-00942-table-or-view-does-not-exist-when-inserting-in) the solution was to change the type of the data from Blob to String but this is not what I'm looking for. I need to insert a Blob in my table.

Here is my code:

```
    public void insert( Connection conn , String id, String imageName, byte[] image ) throws Exception {

    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    Blob img = conn.createBlob();
    img.setBytes(1, image);

    try {

        String sql = "INSERT INTO MY_OWNER.IMAGE_TABLE "
                + "(ID, IMAGE_NAME, BLOB_IMAGE) "
                + "VALUES (?, ?, ?) ";

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        ps.setString(1, id);
        ps.setString(2, imageName);
        ps.setBlob(3, img);

        ps.executeUpdate();

        conn.commit();

    } catch ( Exception e ) {

        conn.rollback();
        throw new Exception ( e );

    } finally {

        if ( ps != null ) {
            ps.close();
        }
        if ( conn != null ) {
            conn.close();
        }

    }

}
```

I'm sure to have privileges and also sure about the syntax. Like I said, I believe the Blob it's bothering.

Here is the error:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1010)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1315)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
```

Do you have any idea what is all about?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so sorry mates :-P

At the end, as the ORACLE error was about grants, it was a grants problem... I didn't realize it because the connection to the DDBB was using another user to connect.
The solution was obviously to give the proper grants to this user.

Again, sorry for loose your time!