# BatchUpdateException:ORA-00942:TABLE OR VIEW DOES NOT EXIST

Tags: oracle, jdbc

This issue occurred in jdbc batch insert. I queried from an Oracle datasource, parsed the resultset and then inserted into another Oracle datasource. I have got the connect metadata and printed the current username along with url, both are invalid.
But when it went to batch update, I got the ora-00942 exception. I'm pretty sure all above works fine in database. Has anyone encountered this exception and can you give me some advice?

EDIT:
Ok, I got a table named `photos` for example in `REMOTE_USER` and I queried from it. It gave me a resultset, then I parse it after that INSERT it to `LOCAL_USER.photos`. I did query the `LOCAL_USER.photos` where I logon in from PL/SQL Developer. The interesting thing was I could do the `select` command but not the `insert`. Below is some part of code.

```
     conn = datasource.getConnection(); // notice that it was target datasource
            DatabaseMetaData connMetaData = conn.getMetaData();
            String userName = connMetaData.getUserName();
            resultSet = ds.getResultSet();
            ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
            int count = metaData.getColumnCount();

      String insertSql = generateInsertSql(count, metaData, userName);
      // this was generated through metaData , the output should be 
      // "insert into LOCAL_USER.photos(col1,col2) values(?,...)"

        logger.error("insert clause is {}", insertSql);
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(insertSql);
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        while (resultSet.next()) { // this was the original datasource
            stageTotalNum++;
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                Object object = resultSet.getObject(i);
                dealClobColumn(ps, i, object);
            }
            ps.addBatch();

            if (stageTotalNum % 500L == 0L) {
                ps.executeBatch(); // throws batchupdateexception.
                ps.clearBatch();
                conn.commit();
            }
        }

        ps.executeBatch();

        conn.commit();
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information? 
Also could you check if all tables in your query are exists and all of this tables are accessible from logged user

Comment: @VasylMoskalov Edit my post,please check it . Thanks for your time.

Comment: Could you please execute your insert clause using same credentials as in `datasource.getConnection()`?

Comment: Check this link if in case it helps you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561650/getting-an-exception-ora-00942-table-or-view-does-not-exist-when-inserting-in

Comment: @VasylMoskalov I didn't know if it is the lob problem.My `photos` table got a blob column which stored the binary data for the images. What I used to query and insert is `getObject` and `setObject`. I ran the application locally and it ran pretty well but when I posted it to remote server the application threw the exception.

Comment: @codeLover Yes, I have read your link. It could be the problem that I deal the blob column incorrectly. But I am wondering if the environment difference between my local oracle database and the remote one as the scenairo  I post to VasylMoskalov

Comment: It is also one of the possibility that your LOCAL_USER does not have insert privilege on photos table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be the `blob` type column which I didn't handle it the right way.
First I queried from original datasource then got the `blob` column of the resultset by
 `conn.getObject(index)` .  Next I insert the blob column into target datasource by `conn.setObject`. Of course that way wasn't working at all, so I changed to the following:

```
 conn.setBlob(rs.getBlob(index)).
```

Although it worked fine in my own environemnt, but when the application ran in remote server, it kept annoying about the 'table or view does not exists'.The third version is:

```
conn.setBinaryStream(rs.getBlob(index).getBinaryStream());
```

Ok, this time it worked both my pc and remote server. Thanks to @codeLover's advice and link, it really hepled me and saved my time. Appreciated it!