# Can't enqueue large text messages onto Oracle AQ via JMS client - ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jms, clob, oracle-aq

I am enqueuing JSON messages onto Oracle AQ on the JVM via the JMS client. This is working fine for small text messages but is failing for larger messages. I believe that this is something to do with Oracle using `VARCHAR` for smaller messages and switching to `CLOB` for messages larger than 4000 characters.

The AQ database script is

```sql
BEGIN
    DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE (
        queue_table => 'MY.AQT_MY_INBOX',
        queue_payload_type => 'SYS.AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE',
        comment => 'QueueTable for MY Inbox Messages',
        multiple_consumers => FALSE,
        sort_list => 'priority,enq_time'
    );

    DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE (
        queue_name => 'MY.AQ_MY_INBOX',
        comment => 'Queue for MY Inbox Messages',
        queue_table => 'MY.AQT_MY_INBOX',
        queue_type => SYS.DBMS_AQADM.NORMAL_QUEUE,
        max_retries => 2880,
        retry_delay => 30
    );

    DBMS_AQADM.GRANT_QUEUE_PRIVILEGE(
        privilege => 'ENQUEUE',
        queue_name => 'MY.AQ_MY_INBOX',
        grantee => 'MY_USER'
    );

    DBMS_AQADM.START_QUEUE (
        queue_name => 'MY.AQ_MY_INBOX'
    );
END;
/
```

The oracle dependencies are configured via Maven as

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>18.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>aqapi_g</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

The exception stack trace is

```
Caused by: oracle.jms.AQjmsException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsUtil.writeClob(AQjmsUtil.java:640)
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsTextMessage.writeLob(AQjmsTextMessage.java:294)
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsProducer.jdbcEnqueue(AQjmsProducer.java:1054)
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsProducer.send(AQjmsProducer.java:747)
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsProducer.send(AQjmsProducer.java:517)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:634)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:608)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.lambda$send$3(JmsTemplate.java:586)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:504)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1052)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:537)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:255)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:610)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:249)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:82)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:924)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1136)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3640)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeInternal(T4CCallableStatement.java:1318)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3730)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3710)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.executeUpdate(OracleCallableStatement.java:4265)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1061)
    at oracle.jms.AQjmsUtil.writeClob(AQjmsUtil.java:605)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498)
    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to put a breakpoint in `AQjmsUtil.writeClob` and I could see that the exception was being thrown for the following

```java
clobStmt = (OracleCallableStatement)db_conn.prepareCall("UPDATE " + queueTable + " tab set tab.user_data.text_lob = ? where tab.msgid = ?");
clobStmt.setString(1, textData);
clobStmt.setBytes(2, msgid);
int count = clobStmt.executeUpdate();
```

The `CLOB` logic is doing an `UPDATE` whereas for smaller strings where `VARCHAR` is used I believe it's only doing an `INSERT`. The offending `UPDATE` statement was

```sql
UPDATE MY.AQT_MY_INBOX tab set tab.user_data.text_lob = ? where tab.msgid = ?
```

The issue was fixed by executing the following `GRANT` script

```sql
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON MY.AQT_MY_INBOX TO MY_USER;
```

The strange thing  about this solution is that I don't need an `INSERT` grant for this table (there's only the `ENQUEUE` grant for the overlying queue). I feel this is a bit of a bug in the oracle implementation and that both the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` grants should be added by the `ENQUEUE` grant. Either that or the JMS API should do a single `INSERT` and not an `UPDATE` for `CLOB` (similar to how `VARCHAR` is implemented)

Comment: All I did is rerun the liquibase script in upper case table name!

Comment: This comment does not provide enough detail to be helpful